# How do we signal a typo in a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I just noticed a typo in the tag `cowboy-behop` - it should be `cowboy-bebop`. I didn't find any link to signal that kind of errors though. Rare as they are, maybe it's not really needed.

Comment: Also related is how to fix spacing typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to fix a typo in a tag (i.e change tag [stak](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stak) to [stack](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack)). These are now two different tags.

Suggest an edit to all questions incorrectly tagged. For a large set do as you had did and post it on this meta. Those with 500 reputation and more should be able to review them in https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits

Since there is currently only one, it would be best to signal the original poster of the question to edit. It will most likely be faster than waiting for someone to see the suggestion in /review.

I removed my typo and the incorrect tag should hopefully be out of system [in about a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) as long as no one uses it.

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to retag or edit the question, you can always flag the question for moderator attention, and describe the problem.